# Claims in Forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I'm working in an asp.net MVC site with Forms Authentication.

The site has a login page that after successfully login it's show certain user data.

The problem is that userName or userId is returning always null after post.

It seems as if the claims are lost after post

Regards, jorge

This is web.config

`<system.web>
 <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="SingleSignOn" loginUrl="~/User/Login" timeout="480" slidingExpiration="true"/>
    </authentication>
    <machineKey validationKey="E4451576F51E0562D91A1748DF7AB3027FEF3C2CCAC46D756C833E1AF20C7BAEFFACF97C7081ADA4648918E0B56BF27D1699A6EB2D9B6967A562CAD14767F163"
            decryptionKey="6159C46C9E288028ED26F5A65CED7317A83CB3485DE8C592" validation="HMACSHA256" decryption="AES" />
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.1" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  </system.web>`

This code shows authenticate private method:

```
 private void AuthenticateUser(string username, bool createPersistenceCookie)
{
  FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
  FormsAuthenticationTicket newAuthTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(username, true, 1);

  FormsIdentity formsIdentity = new FormsIdentity(newAuthTicket);

  var user = (from c in db.Clients
              where c.UserName == username
              select c).SingleOrDefault();

  var claims = new List<Claim>();
  claims.Add(new Claim("UserName", username));
  claims.Add(new Claim("Id", user.ID.ToString()));
  claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Name));
  claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.Email ?? ""));
  // Required for AntiForgeryToken
  claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.ID.ToString()));
  claims.Add(new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider", user.ID.ToString()));
  claims.Add(new Claim("IsAdUser", user.IsAdUser.ToString()));

  var extendedRoles = CalculateEmployeeExtendedRoles(user);
  foreach (var role in extendedRoles)
    claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));

  //Add a claim for the User Name
  formsIdentity.AddClaims(claims);

  //Attach the new principal object to the current HttpContext object
  HttpContext.User = new System.Security.Principal.GenericPrincipal(formsIdentity, new string[] { });

  //Make sure the Principal's are in sync
  System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.User;

  //Set the Forms Authentication Cookie
  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, createPersistenceCookie);
}
```

And this is the razor View that displays user information

```html
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
  using (Html.BeginForm("LogOut", "User", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
  {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Hola " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index", "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
      </li>
      
      <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
    </ul>
  }
}
```